# Standard Algorithm for subdividing a grid into smaller and smaller parts

Tags: algorithm, grid, generator

I'm running a simulation over a grid of parameters and I'd like to run it for as long as possible, but I don't know yet when the simulation will be terminated (think power cut). So what I'd like to do is specify the min and max values for each parameter and then let the loop pick the next best point on the grid, regularly saving the current result.

So given in 1d space a parameter a from 0 to 1 I'd like the loop to simulate for values 0, 1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25, 0.875, 0.625, 0.375, 0.125, ... The exact order does not matter too much, as long as the next point always lies in between the previous ones.

So probably I could come up with some piece of code that generates this sequence, but I'm wondering if there are standard formulations for such an algorithm, especially for higher dimensional spaces?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this in one dimension is to maintain a binary tree, where each node keeps track of an interval, and its midpoint.

The left child of a node contains the left half of its interval, and the right child contains the right half.

Performing a breadth-first search in such a tree and keeping track of all the mid points of the traversed nodes, will yield the sequence you are after.

For several dimensions, depending on your needs, you can e.g. keep track of one such tree for each dimension, and generate your parameters in the order you like.

In practice this can be implemented using lazy initialisation and a queue to perform the BFS.

To demonstrate (but in practice, you would do it in a more memory-efficient way), I've added a simple binary tree DFS implementation in JavaScript (since it can be tried in the browser):

```
class Node {
    constructor(min, max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.mid = (min + max) / 2;
    }

    get left() { return new Node(this.min, this.mid); }
    get right() { return new Node(this.mid, this.max); }
}

function getSequence(start, end, n) {
    const res = [start, end];
    const queue = [new Node(start, end)];
    for (let i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        const n = queue.shift();
        res.push(n.mid);
        queue.push(n.right, n.left);
    }
    return res;
}

getSequence(0, 1, 100);
```